# dismiss modal view with return key

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, modalviewcontroller

I got one UITextField on my Modal view controller.
When "Done" key is clicked, i want to dismiss the modal view.
i don't know where should i add below code to dismiss modal view.
Thanks in advance for any help.

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add it in `UITextFieldDelegate` method

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```